# Send agent to another queues service point

Tags: anylogic

I would like to mix a serpentine line and a straight line queue system where the serpentine line has several service points. I would then like the strait line to use a particular service point of the serpentine lines service points... not the one created with it. Thanks in advance... [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default.

A possible workaround: Use the *servicePoints* as they are in your screenshot right now, but suspend/reactivate the 2 uppermost servicePoints as needed whenever priority customers are present or not. The function to do this is this:

```java
public void setServiceSuspended(ServiceUnit<Q> serviceUnit,
                                boolean suspended)
```

Implemenent checks to make sure both servicePoints cannot be active at the same time.